# How to synchronize toggle selections across pages with JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a need to have a multi-page html, with each page containing an identical toggle. When the user changes a toggle on one page, all the toggles on the other pages should change (or at least change on loading the other pages).

I've created a Fiddle to illustrate a simple scenario, with a two page example and identical toggles on each page. I'd LIKE to be able to change the toggle on page 2 by toggling the toggle on page 1
http://jsfiddle.net/vSr99/

I've tried a number of methods, and yes have included a refresh after attempting to manipulate with javascript, but have not even come close, no doubt due to my programatically challenged nature :-/

If anyone can suggest a simple solution I'd much appreciate it!

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting a global attribute when the button is clicked and store this on $('html') like so:

```
 $('html'). attr('toggleIs',true);
```

then you can check for this on *pagebforeshow* and add the toggled state to the buttons on all new pages being pulled into view depending on the button state.

**EDIT**
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSr99/5/) (ignore the first alert);

Here is the html:

```
$(document).on('change', '.your_select', function(){
  // set
  if( $(this).find('option:selected').val() == "on" ){
       $('html').data('toggle', 'on');
       } else {
       $('html').data('toggle', 'off');
       }
  });

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '.ui-page', function(){

  var that = $(this).find('.your_select');
  // clear
  that.find('option').removeAttr('selected');
  // reset
  if($('html').data('toggle') == "on" ){
      alert("should be on")
      that.find('select option[value="on"]').attr('selected', 'selected')
      } else {
        alert("should be off")          
        that.find('option[value="off"]').attr('selected', 'selected')
        }
 // refresh slider
 ... 
 });
```

please note:

- took me a while to see you where using jquery 1.6.4, so my on-bindings didn't work. If you  want to keep, you need to use *live* for the bindings to also capture pages being pulled in.
- I gave a class to all sliders, to set them together
- I cannot get the JQM slider('refresh') to work on the slider or any parent element... you will have to figure that out by yourself, but the synchronizing is working :-)

Comment: Thanks - this looks to be exactly the sort of thing I am after. Unfortunatley though, I'm not sure how I would implement this on the page - could I trouble you to edit the Fiddle page so I could see a working example?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. When I slide the sliders, and change page, they dont seem to be synchronized. From what you write above, this is due to the refresh not working, correct? In which case, this could be why no matter what I've tried previously I've not been able to get this to work so far... Thanks for the assist, you've helped me get most of the way there (hopefully!)

Comment: no problem. It could be me not getting the slider.refresh to work, too. check the JQM docs, maybe you can get further than I did...